# Return arrays from custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I created a custom hook that takes a string and 3 arrays of `User`s, called `useSearchUsers`

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';

export default function useSearchUsers() {
const searchUsers = useCallback((searchValue, assistants, interested, rejected) => {
const assistantResults = [];
const interestedResults = [];
const rejectedResults = [];

if (searchValue !== '') {
if (assistants.length > 0) {
  assistants.forEach(user => {
    if (user.assistantName.includes(searchValue)) {
      const name = user.assistantName;
      const image = user.assistantImage;
      const id = user.assistantId;

      assistantResults.push({
        id,
        name,
        image
      });
    }
  });
}

if (interested.length > 0) {
  interested.forEach(user => {
    if (user.interestedName.includes(searchValue)) {
      const name = user.interestedName;
      const image = user.interestedImage;
      const id = user.interestedId;

      interestedResults.push({
        id,
        name,
        image
      });
    }
  });
}

if (rejected.length > 0) {
  rejected.forEach(user => {
    if (user.rejectedName.includes(searchValue)) {
      const name = user.rejectedName;
      const image = user.rejectedImage;
      const id = user.rejectedId;

      rejectedResults.push({
        id,
        name,
        image
      });
    }
  });
}
}
}, []);

return searchUsers;
}
```

And on the screen where I want to call that hook I have a TextInput where the user can write a string. Here I have declared the assistants, interested and rejected arrays, but for obvious reasons I'm ommiting them here

```
import useSearchUsers from '../../hooks/assistance/useSearchUsers';
const [eventAssistants, setEventAssistants] = useState([]);
const [eventInterested, setEventInterested] = useState([]);
const [eventRejected, setEventRejected] = useState([]);
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

const searchUsers = useSearchUsers();

export default function Screen(props) {
 return (
   <Container>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <TextInput onChangeText={text => setSearchText(text)} />
        <Button onPress={() => useSearchUsers(searchText, eventAssistants, eventInterested, eventRejected)} />
      </SafeAreaProvider>
   </Container>
 );
}
```

My question is, how can I return the 3 results arrays from the hook and passing them to the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You can return an `array` containing the 3 result arrays.

```
return [assistantResults, interestedResults, rejectedResults];
```

instead of `return searchUsers;`

And to consume it in `Screen` you can destructure the hook's return value.

```
const [assistantResults, interestedResults, rejectedResults] = useSearchUsers();
```